# Java gzip.read and PHP fread() gives different results

Tags: java, php, fread

I have line in Java and in while I get number:

```
i = gzipinputstream1.read(abyte0, j, 4096);
```

From while number:

```
959
1552
1577
1617
1680
```

when I want use in php:

```
$i = fread($handle, 959):
```

while return:

```
959,
959,
959,
5
```

How make that in PHP result will be the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the stream **fully** in. Right now you're instructing [Java](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) to read a length of max 4096 bytes and you're instructing [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to read a length of max 959 bytes.

If the content length is unknown beforehand, then in Java you rather need the [`InputStream#read()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) method which doesn't take any arguments and in PHP the [`stream_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) wherein you omit the maxlength and offset arguments.

Comment: rewrited to: 

`$i = stream_get_contents($handle, 4096, $j);`

but it's show 4096.

Comment: I repeat: *wherein you **omit** the maxlength and offset arguments*. In other words: do *not* specify them. Leave them away. You apparently don't know the content length beforehand. You should also not specify it in Java, unless you're reading in a loop and appending to a byte buffer.

Comment: Omit the maxlength and offset arguments: `$i = stream_get_contents($handle);`.

Comment: Yes i know what: but i get all bytes. I have rewrite one code to php. And if i get in one line all bits i don't now how remade all in PHP.
Java code

` i = gzipinputstream1.read(abyte0, j, 4096);
                   if(i != -1)
                    {
                        j += i;
                        if(j + 4096 > k)
                        {
                            byte abyte1[] = new byte[k += 8192];
                            System.arraycopy(abyte0, 0, abyte1, 0, j);
                            abyte0 = abyte1;
                        }
 }else{
 flag1 = false;
 }
}`

Comment: Update your question. This is hard to understand.